# How to facet plot NetCDF rasters by year

Tags: r, netcdf

I successfully followed the instructions for getting a graph for a single year of NetCDF data by using the data set and code provided here:

http://rpubs.com/boyerag/297592

Like in the link, I uploaded the dataset as `ndvi.array`. I cut off the first year and assigned that subset as `ndvi.slice`. Then used the code:

```
r <- raster(t(ndvi.slice), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), 
ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ 
towgs84=0,0,0"))
r <- flip(r, direction='y')
plot(r)
```

It's easy to do that for any single year, but I'm trying to create a faceted plot of all these rasters. My normal approach for doing this would be using `Facet_grid` in `ggplot2`, but this is a little different than a scatter plot and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

If this were a scatter plot, my approach would have been to do something like:

```
r = ggplot(ndvi.array, aes(lon,lat)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ t)
```

What's the equivalent for dealing with rasters like this?

Comment: Rather than linking to the code, it would be better to provide a minimal example of the code within the example. Makes it a lot easier for those trying to help :)

Comment: Hi Mikey. I certainly didn't intend to be lazy. Rather, I was afraid to pollute working and existing code with a possibly unsatisfying summary. Hopefully my edit helps more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I successfully followed the instructions....

Unfortunately, these are rather bad instructions. Below is how you can do exactly the same thing in (less than?) 1/3 of the steps.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("gimms3g_ndvi_1982-2012.nc4")
plot(b[[1]])

toolik_lon <- -149.5975
toolik_lat <- 68.6275
toolik_series <- extract(b, cbind(toolik_lon,toolik_lat), method='simple')
toolik_df <- data.frame(year= seq(from=1982, to=2012, by=1), NDVI=t(toolik_series))
ggplot(data=toolik_df, aes(x=year, y=NDVI, group=1)) +  geom_line() + ggtitle("Growing season NDVI at Toolik Lake Station") + theme_bw()

ndvi.diff <- b[[31]] - b[[1]]
plot(ndvi.diff)
```

Your question may not be related to that, as it seems to be about how to use `ggplot2` or is it about looping? Please clearly state your question and use example data that comes with R like this:

```
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plot(b)
```

If you want to loop:

```
for (i in 1:nlayers(b)) { plot(b[[i]]) }
```

To use ggplot with facets, you can do something like the below (this is the example from `?rasterVis::gplot`

```
library(rasterVis)
library(ggplot2)

r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(r, r*2)
names(s) <- c('meuse', 'meuse x 2')


theme_set(theme_bw())
gplot(s) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
           facet_wrap(~ variable) +
           scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'blue') +
           coord_equal()
```

But you might prefer

```
 levelplot(s)
```

Comment: Okay wow this is a much more concise way to do it. I'll give an example first for my question with the iris dataset. `p = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()` That gives plot of length and width. Now if I use `p + facet_grid(. ~ Species)` , ggplot separates the graph into different facets for each species. My question: How do I take this raster data and have R separate out the maps into facets for each year of data?

Comment: I have added an example to my answer

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks!